# Get the used color codes in pdf uploaded document. ItextSharp or any similiar library

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext

I am trying to extract color codes used in pdf on similiar way I am extracting text.Is there any .Net library which from I could extract that ? Any example will be more then helpfull.

```
        public string CheckDocument(FileInfo doc)
    {
        var stream = doc.OpenRead();
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(stream);
        StringWriter output = new StringWriter();
        for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
            output.WriteLine(PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i, new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy()));
        return output.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: You use the `SimpleTextExtractionStrategy`. This extraction strategy is for _text_ extraction (using a _simple_ algorithm to arrange the text pieces to get the result string). If you want to extract _color codes_, you quite likely simply need to implement a different extraction strategy. That been said, what exactly do you mean by *extracting color codes*? Do you want a list of color values used as stroke or fill color while drawing a page?

Comment: Yep i want something lile that. I wrote just sample of extracting text that method is available i need the similiar stuff which will return me a color values

Answer (score 1):

You can enumerate colors with [PDF4NET](https://www.o2sol.com/pdf4net/overview.htm) like this:

```
public void EnumerateColors()
{
    PDFFixedDocument document = new PDFFixedDocument("content.pdf");
    PDFContentExtractor ce = new PDFContentExtractor(document.Pages[0]);
    PDFVisualObjectCollection voc = ce.ExtractVisualObjects(false, false);
    for (int i = 0; i < voc.Count; i++)
    {
        switch (voc[i].Type)
        {
            case PDFVisualObjectType.Text:
                PDFTextVisualObject tvo = voc[i] as PDFTextVisualObject;
                if (tvo.TextFragment.Brush != null)
                {
                    PDFRgbColor rgb = tvo.TextFragment.Brush.Color.ToRgbColor();
                    Console.WriteLine("Text fill color: R: {0}; G: {1}; B: {2}", rgb.R, rgb.G, rgb.B);
                }
                if (tvo.TextFragment.Pen != null)
                {
                    PDFRgbColor rgb = tvo.TextFragment.Pen.Color.ToRgbColor();
                    Console.WriteLine("Text stroke color: R: {0}; G: {1}; B: {2}", rgb.R, rgb.G, rgb.B);
                }
                break;
            case PDFVisualObjectType.Path:
                PDFPathVisualObject pvo = voc[i] as PDFPathVisualObject;
                if (pvo.Brush != null)
                {
                    PDFRgbColor rgb = pvo.Brush.Color.ToRgbColor();
                    Console.WriteLine("Path fill color: R: {0}; G: {1}; B: {2}", rgb.R, rgb.G, rgb.B);
                }
                if (pvo.Pen != null)
                {
                    PDFRgbColor rgb = pvo.Pen.Color.ToRgbColor();
                    Console.WriteLine("Path stroke color: R: {0}; G: {1}; B: {2}", rgb.R, rgb.G, rgb.B);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Disclaimer: I work for the company that develops PDF4NET library.

Comment: I just gonna try it out and send u the fb.

Comment: I think that is it but  guess  have not asked for right thing. Sorry for asking u for help @iPDFdev  I am not too much into pdf terminology. I actually need to check is there a fill color into a pdf example here https://paste.pics/a00dfa62675f1b26de34ac8032f529a4 of this color R:209 G:232 B:172

Comment: The link does not work. The solution is the same, you have to loop through all the objects in the PDF file and check if any of them has your desired color. There is no central place in the PDF file where all used colors are stored.

Comment: Working I was catching wrong RGB code that is why I have not get the fill result. Thank you very much. Library is great btw.

Comment: library ExtractText is not working properly btw. Not returning the right text.

Comment: Please submit a ticket to support